# Typescript HOC - requiring a prop on the React component

Tags: typescript

Ah, TS. I'm having trouble forcing an HOC to require all components that uses it to include a property. This is what I have:

```
interface ExpectedComponentProps {
    requiredProp: string;
    [other: string]: any;
}

const withRequiredProp = function<OriginalProps extends ExpectedComponentProps>(
    WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<OriginalProps>
) {
    // here I know requiredProp is defined for the component
}
```

Example usage:

```
const MyNewComponent = withRequiredProp(MyComponent);

// this should be valid
// <MyNewComponent requiredProp="hello" />

// this should throw a TS error
// <MyNewComponent />
```

However, it doesn't enforce the requiredProp as I would expect it to. How did I mess up the syntax here?

Comment: I don't understand. You're saying withRequiredProp to enforce requiredProp on MyComponent (the parameter), so why are you talking about MyNewComponent?

Comment: Sorry I'm not clear! MyComponent can be any arbitrary component that doesn't need to have a `requiredProp` prop on it. But after using withRequiredProp(), I need to enforce that all usages of the *resulting* component (here, MyNewComponent) to have that prop on it.

Comment: Edit: gah, I see what you're saying. The code I posted requires the property on MyComponent, not the component returned by the HOC. My apologies, I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work

```
function withRequiredProp<C extends React.ComponentType<any>>(
  Component: C,
): React.ComponentType<ExpectedComponentProps> {
  return Component //we just return the argument but we said it was 
  // React.ComponentType<ExpectedComponentProps>
}

const MyComponent: React.FC = () => (
  <div>test</div>
);

const MyNewComponent = withRequiredProp(MyComponent);
```

Now, `MyComponent` doesn't enforce requiredProp. But `MyNewComponent` does.

```
<MyComponent /> //OK
<MyNewComponent /> //error
<MyNewComponent requiredProp="hello" /> //OK
```

Comment: @benjamin.keen you're welcome. Also, `C extends React.ComponentType<ExpectedComponentProps>` is probably better than `C extends React.ComponentType<any>`